# Is a 3 element set, with a binary operation like this, a thing in maths?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

If I say I have a set $S$ with an associative commutative binary operation $\oplus$ such that $\bar{x} \oplus x = x$, it's clear I'm talking of a commutative monoid.

Instead, I have a set containing only 3 elements, $S = \{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ and a commutative binary operation $\oplus$ such that
$$
e_i \oplus e_i = e_i \quad \forall i\\
e_i \oplus e_j = e_1 \quad \forall i \neq j\\
$$
Is this a thing?

Comment: Uhm... Is that "2" supposed to be "3"? Then what are $e_2\oplus e_3$ and $e_3\oplus e_2$?

Comment: What are $e_j \oplus e_1$ for $j=1,2$?

Comment: @Gae.S., yes, corrected.

Comment: @Qwertiops, added that the operation is commutative. And also fixed its definition which was incomplete

Comment: @MorganRodgers, "is the thing I described something which has been given a name in mathematics?"

Comment: @MorganRodgers, interesting point, I hadn't thought about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "a thing". In general, a set with a binary operation is called a **magma** (see the Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra))), and what you have described is certainly a magma. Your operation is associative, so this is actually a **semigroup** (see the diagram on the Wikipedia page I linked). In fact, each $i$ has $e_i = e_i\oplus e_i \oplus e_i$, so the object is an **inverse semigroup**. That seems about as far along the diagram as we can progress, since there is no identity element, so it's not a group.